# Can't build Boost 64 bit dynamic libraries, only static

Tags: c++, boost, dynamic, static

I have recently acquired Visual Studio 2010 through Dreamspark, so I can now compile 64 bit applications and libraries.  I then compiled the Boost 1.47 libraries with Bjam using the following line for input.

```
.\b2 -a -d 0 -q -j 4 -d 0 --variant=debug,release --link=shared,static --threading=multi --address-model=32 --toolset=msvc-10.0
```

When I do, I get 4 of each library (static-debug, dynamic-debug, static-release, dynamic-release).
After they are compiled, I move them into another directory called win32libs.  I then use the exact same line to compile the 64 bit versions, but switch the address model to 64 (I know they are almost identical because I copy and past from the same text document I made to make compiling them easy).  When I go into my stage directory after the 64 bit compilation, I only see .lib, no .dll.  Is this an issue with what I'm doing, or is in some way, 64 bit dlls not supported?

Thanks

Comment: I believe you're not supposed to give it the double dashes before options like `link`, `address-model`, etc.

Comment: Just tried removing one of the dashes on all of them and received an "Invalid Option" error.  It all worked with the 32 though, so I can't see what the problem is.  Could it be also that I have c++ express installed along side professional could cause problems?

Comment: @JAKE6459 : Pablo is correct, and he means remove **both** dashes. I.e., your commandline for 32-bit should have been `.\b2 -a -d 0 -q -j 4 -d 0 variant=debug,release link=shared,static threading=multi address-model=32 toolset=msvc-10.0`. When you had the dashes there, those features were simply ignored and the defaults were built.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The options that change how Boost is compiled (as opposed to those that just control b2's execution) are called "features" and must not be preceeded by dashes on the command line.  In your example the features are:

- variant
- link
- threading
- address-model
- toolset

The libraries it generates will be named according to the
[library naming scheme for Boost on Windows](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#library-naming).  lib*.lib are static libraries; other*.lib are the import libs for the corresponding DLLs.

Comment: Also, what is the difference in the stage directory between the static libraries that start with the libboost and boost followed by the same names.

Comment: Technically, according to the documentation these are 'features', not 'properties'. :-]

Comment: @idljarn:  The docs say: "A property is just a (feature, value) pair."  I'll try an edit...